How can we directly access cookie on client side
How can we directly access cookie on client side without interop ?
I tried using interop it worked well but are there no ways to access browser cookie directly.
Following is the script of interop i want to mimic in wasm using dotnet libraries if possible if not please provide reference.
window.cacheHelpers = {
        async addToCache(cacheName, requestUrl, responseData) {
        const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
        const response = new Response(JSON.stringify(responseData), {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        });
        await cache.put(requestUrl, response);
    },
    async getFromCache(cacheName, requestUrl) {
        const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
        const response = await cache.match(requestUrl);
        if (response) {
            const data = await response.json();
            return data;
        }
        return null;
    },
    async deleteFromCache(cacheName, requestUrl) {
        const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
        await cache.delete(requestUrl);
    }
};


Completely avoiding JavaScript interop for cookie access may not be feasible. Because there isn't native support within Blazor for accessing browser cookie APIs without using JavaScript interop.

Blazor is not designed to base on browser functionality such as cookies. Thats why there is the JsInterop approach to call javascript functions which exposes the whole functionality of the browser. If you really want to use cookies for this, there is no way to not use JsInterop. Maybe there is some form of library that exposes these apis in c# but internally, this will also use JsInterop.
Possible alternatives (depending on your needs):

I worked a lot with https://github.com/Blazored/LocalStorage which does store the information on client side but in localstorage, not as a cookie
If you dont need the javascript access to your functions, it might be suitable to use a MemoryCache in your Blazor wasm
If you use an API, you could also improve caching here, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/overview?view=aspnetcore-8.0

